# npm start runs but no output

Tags: github, npm

I got a simple program off github [1](https://github.com/spion/crlint.js) crlint.js that takes a js file and creates a report identifying various measures like Cyclomatic complexity and Halstead value. I updated my node and npm (I'm on a Mac - Sierra). I added a start line in the script section of the package.json file:

```
 "scripts": {
"start": "node crlint",
"test": "echo \"There is an Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
```

}
When I run it in the terminal (input file lib/testutil.js), no errors but no report generated either.

```
npm start [cyclomatic] —lib/toolutil.js
```

This comes back (in the terminal):

```
> crlint@0.1.1 start /Users/cindy/Documents/crlint
> node crlint "lib/toolutil.js"
```

Any thoughts? This is the first time I've used github so am sure I am missing something. I've looked at the posts on this forum about this - didn't find anything useful. Thanks -